# definition of span of a subspace

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

suppose we have a normed separable space $X$ and we have a subspace $L \subset X$. If I defined $L_1 = \text{span}(L,y)$ for some fixed vector $y \in X$. I have it written that if $y \in L$ then $L_1 = L$. Why is this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $L_1$ is the smallest subspace of $X$ that contains both $L$ and $y$. But if $y\in L$, then clearly $L$ is the smallest such subspace.

Comment: where did you get the smallest such subspace definition from? I thought the span of a subspace was just the set of linear combinators of vectors in $L$?

Comment: It's equivalent, the definition will depend on your textbook. But if $y\in L$, then a combination of vectors of $L$ and $y$ will be a vector of $L$, since it's a subspace.

Comment: so in general $\text{span} L = L$?

Comment: Yes, if $L$ is already a subspace.